# How to stop an app after some time?

Tags: android, android-intent

Hei! In my android app I have a button that starts the app Barcode Scanner. I want to stop this app after 2 minutes, for example. How can I do this?

This is my code :

```
qrgame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.qrgame);
qrgame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: When you start an activity, it is up to the started activity to control its own lifecycle. Not to the caller activity.

Comment: that mean that I cant stop this one?

Comment: Not "naturally". You can kill an app the way the app Advanced Task Killer was doing (I don't kow it so well but you can find plenty of examples on SO), but this is definitely not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

you can finish your activity as you can start your activity using

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

you need to pass the same requestcode to this method

```
finishActivity(requestCode);
```

for delay time you can you Thread, Timer etc.

Or you can close your opened activity just implement Timer, thread which will hold you 2 min or as per your requirement then call

```
finish();
```

Comment: Or I could just use an AsyncTask, ha?

Comment: AsyncTask you can used it but I think you need the timer and AsynTask was used for the background process like loading data like images, read large file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `asyncTask` that you execute in the `onCreate` of your app. And in the `AsyncTask` you write a

```
Thread.slepp(120000).
```

After that you can stop your app.

Answer (score 0):

on you on create method put this code

```
new Thread(){
public void run(){
try{
Thread.sleep(120000);
}
catch(Exception e){}
}
}.start();
```

do not forget your to import the Thread or if you use elipse just CRTL+SHIFT+O

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, put whatever you wish to be run in some method and call the method start and stop as such.

```
//Say we place a switch case for the onClickListener

case R.id.btnScan:

    new CountDownTimer(120000, 120000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {            
            stopScanning(); // Stop the application/function here
            button.setText("Scanned");
        }
    }.start();

    startScanning();

    break;
```