# Android RecognizerIntent simple destroy

Tags: android

I use an intent voice recognition, here is the code :

```
/**
 * Fire an intent to start the voice recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Everything works fine. Now I want to stop the voice recognition after 5 seconds for example. I can't figure how to kill the voice recongnition activity.

Comment: I thought Handler were just to perform an action after some time. Could it close an activity launch by an Intent ?

Comment: Whats about the solution mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361987/how-to-stop-an-app-after-some-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To kill the voice recongnition activity you call `finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE)`.
Thus you need to set up a countdown timer for the duration of 5 second, in `onFinish` call  `finishActivity(REQUEST_CODE)`. Start the timer after you call `startActivityForResult`